# How to get map of firebase cloud store data in node js?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

Actually I m making a discord bot list ,I want to show all the bots ,I m using express nodejs.
My data in firebase are as shown below

```
db.collection("bots").doc("12345").set({
prefix:"?",
id:"12345",
server:"5"
})
```

```
db.collection("bots").doc("12346").set({
prefix:"-",
id:"12346",
server:"7"
});
```

---

---

```
const x = require ("express");
const router = x.Router ()
const {db} = require("../app");
  db.collection("bots").
get().then((querySnapshot) => { const x = require ("express");
const router = x.Router ()
const {db} = require("../app");
  db.collection("bots").where("approved", "==", false).
get().then((querySnapshot) => { 
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
   const bot =  doc.data()
   console.log(bot. prefix)
      router.get("/",(req,res) => {
        res.send(bot.id+"=>"+bot.prefix)
                 })
    });
})

module.exports = router;
```

---

Output:

```
12345 => "?"
```

__
Expected output

```
12345 => "?"
12346 => "-"
```

---

When I console,it returns both `prefix`
But when I tried to render it ,it showing only the first one..

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to show a list of documents, follow the recipe shown in the documentation on [getting all documents from a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection):

```
db.collection("bots").get().then((querySnapshot) => { 
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
})
```

I highly recommend studying that, and the rest of, the documentation, as it has code samples for many common use-cases such as this one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to send result after you looped through snapshot.
Try something like this:

```
let results = []
querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    const bot =  doc.data()
    console.log(bot. prefix)
    results.push(bot.id+"=>"+bot.prefix)
});
router.get("/",(req,res) => {
    res.send(results.join('\n'))
})
```