# Firestore Query returns [object Object ] to Browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore

When querying Firestore the browser is returning `[object Object],[object Object]` instead of:

```
{
>    Description: 'This is a job offer',
>    Active: true,
>    Location: 'Warsaw',
>    Name: 'BA in Bank',
>    Deadline: Timestamp { _seconds: 1603317600, _nanoseconds: 0 }
>  }
>  {
>    Description: 'This is another job offer',
>    Location: 'Amesterdam',
>    Name: 'PM job',
>    Active: true,
>    Deadline: Timestamp { _seconds: 1607554800, _nanoseconds: 0 }
>  }
```

This is a route and I would like to pass the array so I can render it on EJS view dynamically.

```
router.get('/projects', async(req, res) => {
    
        var array = [];
        const snapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('projects').get()
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            array.push(doc.data());
        })
    
        res.render('projects', { array })
    
    });
```

Is there a way to pass these object values on the route handler?

Comment: You might want to try stringifying it in your router: `res.render('projects', { JSON.stringify(array) })`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I don't think that will help me, because I won't be able to manipulate it in EJS - even though I get your point.

Comment: Hi @PauloBrás could you please check these both cases [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59121500/trying-to-load-all-firestore-documents-in-node-js) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59580013/how-to-get-map-of-firebase-cloud-store-data-in-node-js) and confirm if they help you? They show different approaches for the router that might help you, including a difference on the order of how you are retrieving the data, that might be the cause for your issue.

Comment: @gso_gabriel thanks for that - it didn't have the answer but it had hints that allowed me to reach the solution! :)

Answer (score 1):

I manage to find the answer thanks to @gso_gabriel suggestion.

It its ok to send Object on your express middleware but then you need to use forEach() on your EJS view so that it loops through your object and extracts the elements.

```
router.get('/projects', async(req, res) => {


    const snapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection("projects").get();
    
    const docs = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())

    res.render('projects', { docs });

});
```

Then on your EJS you need to do `docs.forEach()`

```
 <% docs.forEach(doc => { %>
                            <%- doc.Name; %>
                                <% }); %>
```

And in EJS you can use it to add whatever html elements you wish to have on your front-end.

I hope this helps for future users.